# Inspect element Rulers in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, code-inspection, rulers

I want to know is there any way to view Rulers in Firefox, alike Chrome inspect element rulers.

Chrome shows your current width, ie. Width + padding = current width on Ruler hover.

see below Chrome screenshot for ref.
[image: Google Chrome Inpect element computed heigh/width rulers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been implemented now in new Firefox. And Firefox version 32 and above developer tools are awesome :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can with help of some addons and a little work. All you have to do is draw the ruler and you get the exact dimensions.

[Measure It let's you draw a ruler across any webpage to check the width, height, or alignment of page elements in pixels.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/measureit/)

Also take a look at [PixelZoomer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pixelzoomer/). It takes a screenshot of the current website and provides various tools for pixel analysis. You can zoom into websites (up to 3200%), measure distances and pick colors with an eye dropper.

Hope I helped :) .

Comment: :) I dont want to draw over element, I need it on inspect element as we do it Chrome.

Comment: @STEEL Sorry steel not yet implemented in Firefox but you can surely make a feature request.